# How to hide series via the legend in highstock ?

Tags: highcharts

I have a few series in highstock. In highcharts there is automatically a legend and when I click on a series in a legend, it hides/show it.

Is there a way to have the same behavior in highstock ? I can't seem to find this feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`legend: {enabled: true}` for anyone else looking, I don't know why this is off by default

Comment: Yeah, it's confusing as to why it's disabled by default. This saved me- thanks!